# Problems using jQuery $.ajax to pass data

Tags: asp.net, jquery, json, forms, asp.net-ajax

I'm using ASP.NET and attempting to call a method with a signature of

```
[WebMethod] 
public static string GetInfo(string id){...}
```

using the following javascript:

```
var elementValue = $("#element").attr('id');
var d = "{id : " + elementValue + "}";
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../WebPage.aspx/GetInfo",
            data: d,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                //do this
            }
        });
```

And this is not working. If instead I set `elementValue = 2;` it works fine. If I try to hardcode in a string value for testing purposes e.g. `elementValue = "nameToLookUp";` It fails. Why is this happening, and how do I resolve it?

On a side not, why is `type:` required to be `POST` instead of a `GET`? In the end I just want to pass a string value I want to look up in a DB and retrieving some json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To encode a string, it needs to be quoted (inside your string of JSON)

```
var d  "{id: '" + elementValue + "'}";
```

The "type" is not required to be "POST" by jQuery; what makes you feel that it is? Now, your server code might require it, but that's something I can't help with (in this specific case).

Comment: @Daniel - Safer to pass it as a variable like I have...otherwise a string containing a `'` means trouble.  With the pair syntax jQuery will take care of this.

Comment: @Nick this way of doing it is working, but yours isn't. Any ideas?

Comment: @iboeno - Depends on the server in that case, try `{'id':elementValue}`

Answer (score 2):

You should quote the parameters or change your syntax around like this:

```
var elementValue = $("#element").attr('id');
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../WebPage.aspx/GetInfo",
        data: {'id':elementValue},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            //do this
        }
});
```